# Как создать комментарии на сайте

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: на сайте требуются комментарии, начитавшись статей по правильному структурированию БД, пришёл к выводу, что нужно создать две таблицы: comments и comments_article. В первой хранится comments_id, comments_content и comments_date, во второй user_id и comments_id. С записью комментариев в БД проблем нету, проблема заключается в том, что я не понимаю, как составить запрос для получения comments_id, ведь, если делать по тому же user_id, то результатами выдачи будут все комментарии данного пользователя, если сравнивать по id и content, то, при условии, что пользователь пишет одни и те же комментарии, например, "привет", оно опять же будет выдавать все такие комментарии.

Comment: *на сайте требуются комментарии* К чему? *В первой хранится ..., во второй ...* А что означают эти буквы? какой смысл в значении каждого из указанных полей? PS. С учётом того, что УЖЕ должно существовать, одной таблицы достаточно, вторая нафиг не нужна.

Comment: А если, к примеру, на сайте имеются комментарии к статьям и комментарии к новостям, то есть, это разные вещи, имеющие в бд разные таблицы, как тогда быть и как определить, какие комментарии к чему относятся?

Comment: А это зависит от того, являются ли статьи или новости двумя разными сущностями или одной сущностью с разными значениями некоего атрибута. А ещё - комментарии к комментариям будут? тут не начитываться нужно, а заново проводить анализ предметной области, в новом её состоянии...

Comment: подключите готовую систему комментариев (да хоть от ВК, например) и не дурите ни себе, ни другим голову

Comment: На сайте имеются книги и имеются статьи. К ним должны быть комментарии, в базе это должны быть таблицы book_comments и news_comments, верно? Так как получить это comments_id, записываемый в comments

Comment: Да, будут вложенные комментарии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы завел комментарии в следующем виде:

1. Таблица комментариев: comments (поля id, text, date, page)
   где page - это какой-то идентификатор (адрес) страницы со статьей, книгой или т.д.
2. Вывести все комментарии по данной статье / книге можно с указанием в запросе ее идентификатора (page)

SELECT * from comments WHERE page ='идентификатор_страницы' sort by date DESC

Как-то так :)

Comment: а как, к примеру, сделать, чтобы пользователь мог отвечать на комментарий?

Comment: (как в ВК, например)

Comment: Накручивать функционал можно и дальше, сколько угодно. Только это уже будет что-то другое. Чаты, форумы, система уведомлений и т.д. )))
То, что сделали с каментами в ВК - это лютая жесть, ИМХО.